# How do I transpose rows into columns using SQL? E.g. A Pivot Table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I´m struggling with a query that transposes rows into columns. The challenge is that the number of 'codes' might vary each time I run the select.

So the result of the select would be as follows:

```
 ********   COPA:LN, LBUL:LN, LSIL:LN 
 COPA:LN      1    ,   0.9  ,   0.9   
 LBUL:LN      0.9  ,   1    ,   0.9   
 LSIL:LN      0.9  ,   0.9  ,   1
```

Many thanks!!!

```
CREATE TABLE #myTable
([code1] varchar(15), [code2] varchar(15),  [cor] decimal(18,14));

INSERT INTO #myTable
 ([code1] , [code2],  [cor] )
 VALUES
('COPA:LN'     ,    'COPA:LN'     ,     1),
('LBUL:LN'     ,    'COPA:LN'     ,     0.9),
('LSIL:LN'     ,    'COPA:LN'     ,     0.918356332594718),
('COPA:LN'     ,    'LBUL:LN'     ,     0.93607492424868),
('LBUL:LN'     ,    'LBUL:LN'     ,     1),
('LSIL:LN'     ,    'LBUL:LN'     ,     0.960430401044714),
('COPA:LN'     ,    'LSIL:LN'     ,     0.918356332594718),
('LBUL:LN'     ,    'LSIL:LN'     ,     0.960430401044714),
('LSIL:LN'     ,    'LSIL:LN'     ,     1)
```

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the data? For example: 

* Is there always a 1-1 relationship between codes? Do we need to worry about aggregating or excluding multiple matches?
* When the data changes, is it because new rows are added, or do we need to assume a new set of values with every call?
* Is there a specific order that's necessary to display the columns?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Cahit, but I missed your response. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Pivot Table in MSSQL 2012.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

```
-- Pivot table with one row and five columns
SELECT 'AverageCost' AS Cost_Sorted_By_Production_Days, 
[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM
(SELECT DaysToManufacture, StandardCost 
    FROM Production.Product) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
AVG(StandardCost)
FOR DaysToManufacture IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that the number of columns varies each time I run the select, from 1 to x. 
Your solution works great only if you have a predefined number of columns - in your case [0], [1], [2], [3], [4].

Answer (score 0):

try dynamic pivot

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(code1) 
                    from #myTable
                    group by code1
                    order by code1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
set @query = N'SELECT * from #t

            pivot 
            (
                max(cor)
                for code1 in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end I´m using COALESCE and a dynamic pivot with exec sp_executeSQL @sql.
Thanks !!!